What potential issues with MariaDB database converting from Latin1 to UTF-8
I have a MariaDB database that is set using latin1 but our PHP and HTML specify we are using UTF-8. This is causing some characters to be switched from ' to � and before I switch the database to UTF-8 I figured I would ask for any potential issues anyone has run across when converting the database. The version is 10.0.38-MariaDB-0+deb8u1

make a full backup, nobody can guarantee that it will work, and you have a backup to go back and try something different

See "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

I edited to make it more clear you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are two different products, and they are no longer compatible. We all need to stop thinking of MariaDB as a "type" of MySQL. Even the founder of MariaDB says, "Starting from MariaDB 10.0 we stopped doing merges of code from MySQL..."
